# Setting std::string conditionally

Tags: c++

I have a case where I have to set std::string to NULL. The code is like this:

`const std::string variable = "HOME";
const std::string str = getenv(variable.c_str());`

Problem is, `getenv()` returns NULL if it does not find the environment variable and since we can't set std::string to `NULL` value, we have to assign it an empty string.

One option is:

`const std::string str = (getenv(variable.c_str()) == NULL ? "" : getenv(variable.c_str()));`

Only that it calls getenv() twice.

What is the best practice to achieve this result?

Comment: Why do you need the second `getenv` call? I'm not sure I follow that. It seems like the first one by itself achieves what your first two lines of code did.

Comment: @wolfPack88: To have something on the right side of the ternary statement.

Comment: Ah... read it as two lines, wasn't paying attention. My bad

Comment: By the way, [it isn't called twice](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3303f9913eb2114c).

Comment: @chris I think this case is something like this http://ideone.com/4LhR2B

Comment: @tnkousik, Shoot, right, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the best practice to achieve this result?

Roll your own (wrap it):

```
std::string safe_getenv(const std::string& var)
{
    auto env = getenv(var.c_str());
    return env ? std::string{env} : std::string{};
}

auto result = safe_getenv("blah");
```

Comment: If doing this, I'd probably make it a bit more generic. Something like `T value_or(const T &t, const T &def) {return t ? t : def;}`, but maybe with a performance tweak or two unless it's inlined as is.

Answer (score 5):

```
std::string string_from_char_array(const char* str)
{
  return str ? str : "";
}
```

Then call it like

```
const std::string str = string_from_char_array(getenv(variable.c_str()));
```

Comment: To be a little more clear about what's going on, might it be better to do `return str != null ? str : "";`? I know it's a style issue.

Comment: @MattKline, Personally, pointers as booleans are one of the few things I think make perfect sense.

Comment: @Matt I guess it is a style issue, but then I'm on the side that thinks that comparing a pointer against NULL (or std::nullptr) is needlessly verbose. ;)

Comment: With lambdas you can even do it in one line: `const std::string s = [](char const* str) { return str ? str : ""; }(getenv(v.c_str()));`

Comment: @ComicSansMS Yes, but then you need to write the same thing each time (though it's a simple thing). And I'd say it doesn't improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

> Only that it calls getenv() twice.
>
> What is the best practice to achieve this result?

You could avoid calling it twice by assigning the result of getenv() to an `auto` variable like this

```
    auto var = getenv(variable.c_str();
    const std::string str = (var == NULL ? "" : var);
```

Hope it helps you :)